# Disqus 2012 - How do I remove the Discussion/Community nav?

Tags: css, disqus

I want to remove the Disqus 2012 Discussion/Community nav just for mobile users.  I want non-mobile users to still see it.  Possible with CSS or another method?

Answer (score 0):

You can target mobile users depending on their resolution, using media queries. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/ , and having a class on that link so you can easily target it in your css.

Comment: I know about media queries, but according to Disqus, I can only change colors with CSS.  http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/545277-disqus-2012-appearance-tweaks

Comment: It will work if you overwrite their css using `!important;` at the end of the css line you are trying to change. Something like `a {display:none !important;}`